# Openlayers HiDPI/Retina Screen with standard resolution raster tiles?

Tags: raster, openlayers, tiles, retina

My Openlayers application can display tiled rasters from arbitrary online sources.  It will parse capabilities from any user-specified URL for WMTS, TMS, OSM, XYZ or WMS services and present the user with a list of available layers which they can choose from.

Many of these layers are only available in standard resolution, but most of the users will be using Retina or high DPI screens.  The result is that the map features are all too small, thin and spidery looking and text is very difficult to read for people with standard eye sight (impossible for anyone with aging eyes).

Is there some way to get Openlayers to display these standard resolution tiles at double the resolution (or x1.3 or x3 or whatever the screen scale is)?

Ie, To display the normal 256x256 tiles at 512x512 pixels?

I know this would make the rasters look a little blurry, but in theory no more so than if they were displayed on a standard resolution screen.  At least they'd be big enough to view/read properly - and I can give the user the option of whether to use this feature or not.  I've verified that the rasters look fine at double size by magnifying the view in which they are displayed by 2x, but of course this magnifies everything else in the web page too, which is undesirable  Eg, widgets are double-sized, vector layer symbology gets blurry.

I can easily scale vector symbology, just my multiplying the various `width` and `size` parameters by the screen scale factor (this is tested and working), but I cannot do anything similar for rasters.  So I think the best work around would be to show them at double size.  Eg, grab the tiles that would normally be used if zoomed out by 2x and display them at 2x their actual size.

It seems that this should be possible but I can't figure out how it would be done.  Perhaps redefining all the layer's resolutions and setting `tilePixelRatio = 0.5` might be part of the solution, but my Openlayers knowledge is limited and I'm not sure if this is even on the right track.

I expected a lot of other people must be trying to deal with the same issue, but I've been unable to find any information that fits this scenario.

Is this possible?  How can it be done?

**JSFIDDLE UNSUITABLE TO DEMO THIS ISSUE:**

I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate this ( https://jsfiddle.net/nsands/n3cbwr95/20/ ) but jsfiddle is not suitable in this case, as it and/or iOS does its own strange scaling on the iPhone retina screen.  With iPhone in portrait mode, everything is too tiny (not just the map, but even the HTML and Javascript panes have text that is unusually small), and when in landscape mode, the map text is large enough, but appears to have been scaled up (it is blurry - actually the kind of behaviour I **WANT** to achieve elsewhere, but only for raster layers).

**ACTUAL DEMO OF THIS ISSUE:**

However, this issue can be demonstrated using the WMTS example on the Openlayers examples page at:  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts.html

I've loaded this up on both a standard resolution desktop PC and on a 'retina' (HiDPI) iPhone 6S and focused on the same location at the same zoom level on both devices.  Below is what it looks like on both (note that the retina image is actually double the resolution shown here, but is the same size as shown here - and it is the size of the elements that is the problem for me).

Note that the elements in the HiDPI/'Retina' version are about half the size of the elements in the standard resolution version.  For some people, this is too small to read, and on some maps the elements are rendered even smaller than this.

OpenStreetMap uses fairly large fonts when rendering its tiles.  Some map services (such as that provided by my state government) use smaller fonts, and are completely unreadable in Openlayers on retina/HiDPI screens (ie, https://services.thelist.tas.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/Topographic/ImageServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml ).

STANDARD RESOLUTION:

[image: Standard Resolution]

'RETINA' (SCALED TO ACTUAL SIZE):

[image: Retina (scaled to actual size)]

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle showing what's wrong otherwise you will get no answer.

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't work well for this (see example added to post) as it does some weird scaling of its own on the iPhone retina screen (although it does still look terrible there, even when it does scale it up).  However, I've added another clear demo as well and linked to the HTML/Javascript (ie, the Openlayers example site).

Comment: I think http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/wmts-hidpi.html is what your are looking for.

Comment: @oterral, as far as I can tell, that example is for high DPI WMTS tiles.  I need to be able to use standard DPI tiles since high DPI tiles are not available on all services.  I want these standard DPI tiles to be rendered at double the size they usually appear on a high res screen.

Comment: Can you just call the specific resolution you want vis TMS?

Comment: What do you mean?   Can you please explain further?   As I've already explained, some services only have one standard resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no coincidence about the location, it was based on your jsfiddle example.  I've now taken a copy of your function and extended it to work for OSM, XYZ, WMS, WMTS and Bing.  You are right about OSM, the constructor is simply shorthand for an XYZ source with

```
url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
attributions: ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION,
```

However, those properties can be read back regardless of which constructor is used (the url will be converted to a urls array).

getTileSize() and getOrigin() actually take an argument (the zoom level).  In some services for non-3857 projections there are sometimes different values for each level.  It's even possible to have tiles which aren't square.  I've converted everything to arrays to be compatible with those.  Also the slicing technique isn't compatible with non-3857 services where the resolutions can be irregularly spaced, instead each element of the array needs to be divided by 2 (also dividing means a different scaling constant could be used).  For Bing it was necessary to separate the construction of the returned layer and the setting of the source in the layer via a callback as Bing sources load asynchronously.

```
function newLayerXYZ(sourceType, sourceOptions, layerOptions) {

var layer = new ol.layer.Tile(layerOptions);
var source;
switch(sourceType) {
case "osm":
    source = new ol.source.OSM(sourceOptions);
    setSource2();
    break;
case "xyz":
    source = new ol.source.XYZ(sourceOptions);
    setSource2();
    break;
case "wms":
    source = new ol.source.TileWMS(sourceOptions);
    setSource2();
    break;
case "wmts":
    source = new ol.source.WMTS(sourceOptions);
    setSource2();
    break;
case "bing":
    source = new ol.source.BingMaps(sourceOptions);
    var onKey = source.on("change", function() {
        if (source.getState() == 'ready') {
            ol.Observable.unByKey(onKey);
            setSource2();
        }
    });
    break;
}
return layer;

function setSource2() {
    var urls = source.getUrls();
    var projection = source.getProjection();     // returns a projection object even if set using a string
    var logo = source.getLogo ? source.getLogo() : undefined;  // deprecated in OL5, logos should be included in attributions
    var attributions = source.getAttributions();  // OL3/4 return an object array, OL5 returns a function
    var attributions2;
    if (!Array.isArray(attributions)) {
        attributions2 = source.getAttributions2 ? source.getAttributions2() : attributions;  // special case for Bing with OL4.5/4.6
        if (attributions2) {
            attributions2 = attributions2.bind(source);  // bind needed if custom functions use 'this'
        }
    } else {
        attributions2 = [];                      // must be set as an html array
        for (var i = 0; i < attributions.length; i++) {
            attributions2[i] = attributions[i].getHTML();
        }
    }
    var grid = source.getTileGrid();
    var resolutions = grid.getResolutions().slice(); // take a copy, leave original source unaltered for the WMS tileUrlFunction
    var origins = [];
    var tileSizes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < resolutions.length; i++) {
        origins[i] = grid.getOrigin(i);
        tileSizes[i] = grid.getTileSize(i);
        if (!Array.isArray(tileSizes[i])) {
            tileSizes[i] = [tileSizes[i], tileSizes[i]];
        }
        if ( doubleSymbologySizes ) {
            tileSizes[i][0] = tileSizes[i][0] * scaling;
            tileSizes[i][1] = tileSizes[i][1] * scaling;
            resolutions[i] = resolutions[i] / scaling;
        }
    }
    var tileUrlFunction = source.getTileUrlFunction().bind(source);  // bind needed if custom functions use 'this'
    var source2 = new ol.source.XYZ({
        urls: urls,
        projection: projection,
        attributions: attributions2,
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
                resolutions: resolutions,
                tileSizes: tileSizes,
                origins: origins,
            }),
        logo: logo,
        tileUrlFunction: tileUrlFunction  // essential for Bing, WMS and WMTS but is valid for all
    });
    source2.set("originalSource", source);  // makes the WMS/WMTS parameters accessible if required
    layer.setSource(source2);
}
```

}

There's a new demo at http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/tasmania-xyz.htm and http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/tasmania-xyz.htm?false will show a standard display for each layer.

The only limitation I've noticed is that OL fails to read Bing attributions when using OL 4.5.x and 4.6.x, which I eventually discovered was due to an OL change where the new functionality is only available using ol-debug.js.  Apart from that it now appears to be compatible with OL 3.20.0 through to 5.1.3 (using full builds of OL5).  It even works with my UK Ordnance Survey OpenSpace setup, an unusual service with parameters changing at each level which needs customisation ( original maps at http://mikenunn.16mb.com/map/ol3-os-map-basic.htm and http://mikenunn.16mb.com/map/ol3-os-map-basic-wms.htm ) although the pure WMS implemention where changes are needed after the layer is created does need to access the original source to do that, which can be now done from the new source via .get("originalSource").

Comment: I've now edited the code as there was no need for a special case for WMTS when creating souce2, Using the tilelUrlFunction from the original source takes care of that just as it does for WMS and Bing.

Comment: I've worked through your code and implemented something similar in my app.  It is working for everything I need apart from TMS now.  Here's how I create a TMS source in OL before deriving a new scaled source from it:  `new ol.source.TileImage({
 projection: projCode,
 tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
  extent: extent,
  tileSize: tileSize,
  origin: origin,
  resolutions: resolutions,
  }),
 attributions: attributions,
 tileUrlFunction: function(coordinate) {
 return url + coordinate[0] + '/' + coordinate[1] + '/' + coordinate[2] + ext;
 }
});`

Comment: TMS is really only an XYZ with the y axis reversed.  I suspect your setup would work equally well as ol.source.TileImage or ol.source.XYZ  Try passing the options to the function with "xyz" as the parameter.  You might also be able to use
`    url: url + "{z}/{x}/{-y}" + ext,
which would avoid needing a tile url function.

Comment: I just checked the OL code and the only difference between the TileImage and XYZ constructors seems to be that XYZ will default the tileGrid and projection to 3857 if you don't specify them.

Comment: I'm trying this out, but it's producing some weird results.  The URLs it's producing have the wrong Y value.  If I use {y} in the URL, I get numbers such as "-521", for example, as expected.  And if I manually remove the "-" from such a URL, it loads a tile that fits the area I was looking at.  But if I put {-y} in the URL, I get numbers such as "1541", which is way out of range and doesn't work, of course.  I can't figure out, just yet, why it's not simply negating the numbers, but I'm still looking into it.

Comment: What happens if you keep the custom tile url function?  That's what I did with my Ordnance Survey layer.  e.g.:
`code`
    var layer = newLayerXYZ("xyz", { projection: projCode, tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({ extent: extent, tileSize: tileSize, origin: origin, resolutions: resolutions, }), attributions: attributions, tileUrlFunction: function(coordinate) { return url + coordinate[0] + '/' + coordinate[1] + '/' + coordinate[2] + ext; } });`code`

Comment: TMS sources seem quite rare now but I eventually found one for New York.
When you use {-y} it seems you need to flip the y axis on the origin as well, i.e. set 
`origin: [origin[0], -origin[1]],`
There's a working example with both the {-y} and custom url methods at http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/nyc.htm

Comment: hmmm... still can't get this to work for my EPSG:28355 TMS service I'm testing with (on my home computer so I can't publish the URL).  I've tried it with `{-y}` and with the`-origin[1]`, but the URLs it calls end up having way out of range 'y' values (but different to the out-of-range values I get without the origin inversed).  I've also tried it with the old tileURLFunction.  this works OK for the normal source, but when scaled, it produces URLs with all components out of whack.  I'm still looking into it, but I don't have much spare time so it will likely take me a while.

Comment: I've taken a look at the OL code in tileurlfunction.js.  It's using the height of the extent in the {-y} calculation.  Flipping the sign of the y coordinate of the top or bottom corner of 3857 and other projections which are symmetrical across the equator works because it's equivalent to adding/subtracting the height of the full extent.  Any other projections or restricted extents will need an explicit add or subtract.

Comment: I've recently upgraded to OL 6.5.0 and due to some other issues have totally reworked my WMTS code.  Now I can't get this scaled tiles method to work for WMTS layers.  I think it's because the URLs don't have {x} {y} {z} components, and therefore it cannot make an XYZ source that's functional.

Answer (score 3):

From v3.20.0 right through to the current v5.0.3 you can set fake resolutions and tile sizes in the tile grid proportionately scaled up and down relative to the real ones and OL will render those regardless of the actual tile size.  Here's a simple demo based on your jsfiddle.  http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/tasmania.htm

It's seems to be an undocumented feature and earlier versions of OL3 rendered using the real tile size received from the server so the result would have been a mess.  I've used the technique to fix problems with reprojecting raster layers where OL typically chooses smaller areas (i.e. tiles from detailed z levels) to suit its reprojection algorithm but at the view resolution the resulting compression makes them illegible.

Comment: Hey, this is so simple and it actually works.  Thanks so much - after I gave up on this over a year ago, I have gone back to my project and mostly got it working the way I want now.  If you would add some more details to your answer on actual implementation, I would like to mark this as the correct answer.  In the meantime, I will add my own answer with some details of what I did.

Comment: Mike, is there any simpler/built in solution for this by now? I'm porting Leaflet map to OpenLayers and Leaflet has simple raster layer option `detectRetina`. Hacked solution in Leaflet is to set `tileSize` option to `512` and `zoomOffset` to `-1` (seems similar to your solution for OpenLayers).

Comment: I don't know of anything else for normal tiles, but if you have a retina tile source you can use them as standard 512px tiles simply but substituting the `tilePixelRatio` setting with `tileSize` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61150507/openlayers-with-osm-retina-tiles-text-too-small/61160142#61160142

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED & IMPROVED for OL 6.5.0 and WMTS**

This answer is essentially an expansion and (hopefully) an improvement on @Mike's answer(s).  I found that the solution I had been using no longer worked for some WMTS sources, after reworking my WMTS code to better fit in with some changes after upgrading from OL 3.x to OL 6.5.0.  The WMTS solution below should work for any WMTS or XYZ source, I think.

Note that my project needs allow for dynamically created layers, where the user inputs the details of the data source (eg, the URL template, for XYZ tile layers, or the capabilities URL for WMTS then select from layer name and matrix set ID).  AND it must work for XYZ (inc., OSM), TMS and WMTS.  Therefore I have to develop solutions for all 3 of those tile layer types (plus WMS as well).

My working solutions for XYZ (inc. OSM) and WMTS tile layers are below.  I still need to refine this solution further for TMS and (tiled) WMS, but similar principles should apply there (ie, multiplying the tile sizes by the scale factor and dividing the resolutions by the scale factor).

(These functions do share some code, which should probably be broken out into a separate function called by each of them.)

**WMTS:**

```js
function scaledWMTSSource(origSource) {
    var urls = origSource.getUrls();
    var grid = origSource.tileGrid;
    var resolutions = grid.getResolutions().slice(); // take a copy, leave original source unaltered
    var origins = [];
    var tileSizes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < resolutions.length; i++) {
        origins[i] = grid.getOrigin(i);
        tileSizes[i] = grid.getTileSize(i);
        if (!Array.isArray(tileSizes[i])) {
            tileSizes[i] = [tileSizes[i], tileSizes[i]];
        }
        if ( symbologyScale > 1 ) {
            tileSizes[i][0] = tileSizes[i][0] * symbologyScale;
            tileSizes[i][1] = tileSizes[i][1] * symbologyScale;
            resolutions[i] = resolutions[i] / symbologyScale;
        }
    }

    var newSource = new ol.source.WMTS({
        urls: origSource.getUrls(),
        layer: origSource.getLayer(),
        matrixSet: origSource.getMatrixSet(),
        format: origSource.getFormat(),
        projection: origSource.getProjection(),
        style: origSource.getStyle(),
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                origins: origins,
                resolutions: resolutions,
                tileSizes: tileSizes,
                matrixIds: origSource.getTileGrid().getMatrixIds(),
                extent: origSource.getTileGrid().getExtent(),
        }),
    });
    
    newSource.setTileUrlFunction(origSource.tileUrlFunction);

    return newSource;
}
```

**XYZ:**

```js
function scaledXYZSource(origSource) {
    var urls = origSource.getUrls();
    var grid = origSource.tileGrid;
    var resolutions = grid.getResolutions().slice(); // take a copy, leave original source unaltered for the WMS tileUrlFunction
    var origins = [];
    var tileSizes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < resolutions.length; i++) {
        origins[i] = grid.getOrigin(i);
        tileSizes[i] = grid.getTileSize(i);
        if (!Array.isArray(tileSizes[i])) {
            tileSizes[i] = [tileSizes[i], tileSizes[i]];
        }
        if ( symbologyScale > 1 ) {
            tileSizes[i][0] = tileSizes[i][0] * symbologyScale;
            tileSizes[i][1] = tileSizes[i][1] * symbologyScale;
            resolutions[i] = resolutions[i] / symbologyScale;
        }
    }
    var tileUrlFunction = origSource.tileUrlFunction.bind(origSource);  // bind needed if custom functions use 'this'
    var newSource = new ol.source.XYZ({
        urls: urls,
        projection: origSource.getProjection(),
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
            resolutions: resolutions,
            tileSizes: tileSizes,
            origins: origins,
            extent: origSource.getTileGrid().getExtent(),
        }),
    });
    
    newSource.setTileUrlFunction(tileUrlFunction);  // essential for Bing, WMS but is valid for all
    //newSource.set("originalSource", origSource);  // not used - just for informational purposes
    
    return newSource;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also mentioned WMS in the original question.  That can also be done but is slightly more complicated since OL would pass the (fake) tile width/height to the WMS service.  First problem a cached WMS service restricted to one size might not accept the request, and second problem with a bigger tile there would be no magnification.  I've always got around that by setting up the WMS layer as an XYZ layer and simply added the bbox to a tile url preset with the other WMS parameters including the real tile size.  But that wouldn't be practical for dynamically created layers.  Instead you would need to wrap the default WMS tile url function of a proper WMS layer inside a custom tile url function which resets fake tile sizes in the url back to real sizes before it's used to load tiles.  Here's a reworked example using both techniques http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/tasmania-wms.htm Hopefully you'll see from the source what I've done better than I can explain in words.

Comment: WMS is not so critical, but I should also include it, so thanks for this additional information.  I will check it out.  (And bonus points for your examples all focusing on somewhere that's only 20 minute drive from where I live - was that deliberate, or coincidence?)

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/xyz-retina.html

Add

```
 <
    meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"
    >
```

to your page may be useful.
As you can see from the below scrennshot, it works fine on Apple Devices.
[image]

Comment: I'm aware of this optino, but this requires the server to have a separate set of tiles available (see the "2x" in the URL of that example).  Therefore this is not an option.  I need this to work for a map image service that does NOT cater explicitly for high resolution screens.